# NAT translation timeout for DNS on linux

Tags: dns, netfilter, conntrack

In cisco routers they seem to be able to change the NAT translation timeout for DNS separately from udp.

> When port translation is configured, there is finer control over  translation entry timeouts, because each entry contains more context  about the traffic using it. Non-DNS UDP translations time out after 5  minutes; DNS times out in 1 minute. TCP translations time out after 24  hours, unless a RST or FIN is seen on the stream, in which case it times  out in 1 minute.

from: https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/quot-ip-nat-translation-timeout-quot-command/ta-p/3137012

How can I do this on linux?

When I do `sysctl net.netfilter` I can find conntrack timeout viables for each protocol such as

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 120
```

but I can't find any settings for DNS.

Is there a way to change the DNS conntrack timeout viable independently from other udp traffic?

---

If this is not possible by changing the conntrack settings how can I change the DNS conntrack timeout? (I just want to try this for fun no big reason) Should I write some C code to check each udp packet that goes through the NAT using netfilter and then use conntrack to add it to the table with a different timeout variable?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the DNS timeout by using [nfct](https://git.netfilter.org/conntrack-tools/tree/README.nfct)

First create a special contrack timeout policy:

```
sudo nfct add timeout dns-timeout-test inet udp unreplied 20 replied 20
```

Then refer to this policy for DNS packages:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --dport 53 -j CT --timeout dns-timeout-test
```

Then check the DNS conntrack entry with `conntrack -E`
Packets with dport 53 will have timeout of 20 instead of the default 30.

```
[NEW] udp      17 20 src=someaddress dst=someaddress sport=someport dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=someaddress dst=someaddress sport=53 dport=someaport
```